# SQL Server - Schema only replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, database-schema

Is there a way to replicate only schema (and all schema objects) without data between two SQL server instances?

Answer (score 1):

For copying, rather than replicating, the simplest way would be to "Create scripts" for the database and run them on target server. This will create a new blank database on the new server.

Replicaton in SQL server implies that as you make changes to one schema they are automatically replicated on the other server. This can be done to some extent with SQL server replication, you just prevent he data being transferred but setting a criteria. I don't see how this would be of much use though.

Comment: I have data warehouse databases on two SQL Server prod instances.
Both of them are exactly the same. Even datasource (external systems) are the same. 
The difference is only in data load schedule and in applications that use my datawarehouses. 
I just wanted to make my life easier with deployments. 
Now I have to deploy database updates on two instances separately.
It seems that some automation on deployment procedure is the right approach then.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found this researching something else so I don't know if it is still an issue for you or not but there is an object in SSIS called Transfer SQL Server Objects.  I haven't used it before but it has an option to copy data or not and you can select copy all objects or just specific types of objects, permissions etc.